# compile error on FirebaseHandle

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I got compile error when I tried to keep a reference to the handled returned by observeEventType call as suggested in the firebase iOS doc

```
firebaseHandle = messagesRef.observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

error is:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'UInt' to a value of type 'FirebaseHandle!'
```

this is the code from the firebase doc I was trying to follow:

```
var handle = ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println("Snapshot value: \(snapshot.value)")
})
ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How have you defined firebaseHandle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `observeEventType` returns a `Uint` ( `UInt8` actually ). So your `firebaseHandle` variable should be defined like that :

```
var firebaseHandle: UInt8 = 0
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply! according to the doc, it's supposed to return a FirebaseHandle object though. 
- (FirebaseHandle)observeEventType:(FEventType)eventType withBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( FDataSnapshot *snapshot ))block

I miss read the original example, I thought I need to call "handle.remove". So handle being a UInt wouldn't make sense. But it's actually Firebase.remove(handle)